Error while trying to create variables for title and price through Stripe embedded checkout
I keep getting the error, Stripe error :"You must specify either product or product_data when creating a price". I'm a bit lost in how to fix this issue and would very much appreciate some help.
I'll put all the relevant code below, thank you!
server.js
app.post('/checkout', async (req, res) => {
    const { title_wa, price_wa} = req.body

    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        line_items: [
            {
                price_data: {
                    currency: 'usd',
                    product_data: {
                        name: title_wa,
                    },
                    unit_amount: price_wa,
                },
                quantity: 1
            },         
        ],
        mode: 'payment',
        shipping_address_collection: {
            allowed_countries: ['US', 'BR']
        },
        success_url: `${process.env.BASE_URL}/complete?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
        cancel_url: `${process.env.BASE_URL}/cancel`
    })

    res.redirect(session.url)
})


index.ejs
<div class="checkOut">
                    <form id="checkout-form" action="/checkout" method="POST">
                        <input type="submit" value="checkout">
                    </form>

                    <div class="closeShopping">
                        <p> x </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
//code break 

function addItemtoStripe(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            var button2 = event.target
            var StripeItem = button2.parentElement.parentElement
            var title_wa = StripeItem.getElementsByClassName('title')[0].innerText;
            var price_wa = StripeItem.getElementsByClassName('thingPrice')[0].innerText;
            var form = document.getElementById('checkout-form');
            
            fetch('/checkout', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ title_wa: title_wa, price_wa: price_wa })
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                window.location.href = data.url; // Redirect to the Stripe session URL
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
        }

I tried this, however things just got even funkier and I back tracked.
 try {
        // Create a product in Stripe first (if not already created)
        const product = await stripe.products.create({
            name: title_wa,
            type: 'good', // adjust type as per your product type
        });

        // Create a price associated with the product
        const price = await stripe.prices.create({
            currency: 'usd',
            unit_amount: price_wa,
            product: product.id,
        });


The error message suggests that either product or product_data was missing in the request but product_data is indeed specified in your code. I've also tested your code but I'm unable to reproduce the problem. I'd recommend reaching out to Stripe support with the relevant request ID.
